# What is the formal name for an information block in a webpage?

Tags: website-design, terminology, information-architecture, tutorial

The upper right of the following page has a block labelled "How to Format". What's the formal name for this element in GUI design?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the heading itself (circled) or the entire section including the heading and the block below it?

Comment: It might also be worth adding a starting point with common options, so that the user isn't presented with an empty screen. Nice example here: http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/BlankSlate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would call it an **Inline Help Box** which can take many forms and shapes. Take a look at [UI Patterns: Inline Help Box](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/InlineHelpBox), where they explain the following:

> Use to gently introduce functionality to the new and untrained user.

...which is exactly what "How to format" in your screenshot is meant to do.